# Google Maps API not working above API 23 due to run time issues

Tags: android, google-maps-markers, android-6.0-marshmallow, google-maps-api-2

The Problem: Maps API is working fine below API 23 but due to runtime issues, they are not getting permissions somehow on the first run. They ask for permissions the first time, but do not work for the first time. When I run the app, the second time, it works fine on API above 23 as well. But for the first run, it does not work. What this code should do, and does the second time, is ask the user to put two markers, one by one and reverse geocode it using the coordinates selected by user.

```
import android.Manifest;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.location.Address;
import android.location.Geocoder;
import android.location.Location;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompat;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.support.v4.content.ContextCompat;
import android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.android.gms.common.ConnectionResult;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationListener;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationRequest;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationServices;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdateFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.OnMapReadyCallback;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.Marker;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Locale;


public class MapsActivity extends FragmentActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback,
        GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks,
        GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener,
        LocationListener {

    private GoogleMap mMap;
    GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;
    Location mLastLocation;
    Marker mCurrLocationMarker;
    LocationRequest mLocationRequest;
    public Button homeLocationFromPin;
    public Button officeLocationFromPin;
    public static double homeLatitude;
    public static double officeLatitude;
    public static double homeLongitude;
    public static double officeLongitude;
    public int count = 0;
    public MarkerOptions placedHomeMarker;
    public MarkerOptions placedOfficeMarker;
    public static final int LOCATION_REQUEST_CODE = 99;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps);

        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission
                (this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
                && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission
                (this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

            requestPermission(Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION,
                    LOCATION_REQUEST_CODE);
        }



        // Obtain the SupportMapFragment and get notified when the map is ready to be used.
        SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(map);
        mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);

        homeLocationFromPin = (Button) findViewById(R.id.confirmHomeLocation);
        homeLocationFromPin.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                if (String.valueOf(homeLongitude) != null && String.valueOf(homeLatitude) != null) {
                    //Get nearby Places here based on Latitude and Longitude
//                    Toast.makeText(MapsActivity.this, getAddress(homeLatitude, homeLongitude), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    showAlertBoxForHomeLocationConfirmation(getAddress(homeLatitude, homeLongitude));
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(MapsActivity.this, "Please drop pin to home location first", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }
        });


        officeLocationFromPin = (Button) findViewById(R.id.confirmOfficeLocation);
        officeLocationFromPin.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                if (String.valueOf(officeLatitude) != null && String.valueOf(officeLongitude) != null) {
                    //Get nearby Places here based on Latitude and Longitude
//                    Toast.makeText(MapsActivity.this, getAddress(homeLatitude, homeLongitude), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    showAlertBoxForOfficeLocationConfirmation(getAddress(officeLatitude, officeLongitude));
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(MapsActivity.this, "Please drop pin to home location first", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }
        });


    }//End Of OnCreate

    @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
        mMap = googleMap;
        mMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_HYBRID);
        LatLng boston = new LatLng(42.3601, -71.0589);
        mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(boston));
        mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(15));

        showAlertBox("Home");

        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {

            if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                buildGoogleApiClient();
                mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
                Toast.makeText(this, "Inside Perm", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                mMap.setOnMapClickListener(new GoogleMap.OnMapClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onMapClick(LatLng latLng) {

                        if (count == 0) {
                            //Make the confirm button available on first tap
                            homeLocationFromPin.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                            //add(point);
                            mMap.clear();
                            placedHomeMarker = new MarkerOptions().position(latLng);
                            placedHomeMarker.title("Home Location");
                            mMap.addMarker(placedHomeMarker);
                            homeLatitude = latLng.latitude;
                            homeLongitude = latLng.longitude;
                            Toast.makeText(MapsActivity.this, getNameOnly(homeLatitude, homeLongitude), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        } else {
                            officeLocationFromPin.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                            placedOfficeMarker = new MarkerOptions().position(latLng);
                            placedOfficeMarker.title("Office Location");
                            mMap.addMarker(placedOfficeMarker);
                            officeLatitude = latLng.latitude;
                            officeLongitude = latLng.longitude;
                            Toast.makeText(MapsActivity.this, getNameOnly(homeLatitude, homeLongitude), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            Toast.makeText(MapsActivity.this, getNameOnly(officeLatitude, officeLongitude), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                    }
                });
            } else {

            buildGoogleApiClient();
            mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
            mMap.setOnMapClickListener(new GoogleMap.OnMapClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onMapClick(LatLng latLng) {
                    if (count == 0) {
                        //Make the confirm button available on first tap
                        homeLocationFromPin.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        //add(point);
                        mMap.clear();
                        placedHomeMarker = new MarkerOptions().position(latLng);
                        placedHomeMarker.title("Home Location");
                        mMap.addMarker(placedHomeMarker);
                        homeLatitude = latLng.latitude;
                        homeLongitude = latLng.longitude;
                        Toast.makeText(MapsActivity.this, getNameOnly(homeLatitude, homeLongitude), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    } else {
                        officeLocationFromPin.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        placedOfficeMarker = new MarkerOptions().position(latLng);
                        placedOfficeMarker.title("Office Location");
                        mMap.addMarker(placedOfficeMarker);
                        officeLatitude = latLng.latitude;
                        officeLongitude = latLng.longitude;
                        Toast.makeText(MapsActivity.this, getNameOnly(homeLatitude, homeLongitude), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        Toast.makeText(MapsActivity.this, getNameOnly(officeLatitude, officeLongitude), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                }
            });
        }
        }
    }//End of onMap Ready

    protected synchronized void buildGoogleApiClient() {
        mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
                .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
                .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
                .addApi(LocationServices.API)
                .build();
        mGoogleApiClient.connect();
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnected(Bundle bundle) {

        mLocationRequest = new LocationRequest();
        mLocationRequest.setInterval(1000);
        mLocationRequest.setFastestInterval(1000);
        mLocationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_BALANCED_POWER_ACCURACY);
        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,
                Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)
                == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates(mGoogleApiClient, mLocationRequest, this);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionSuspended(int i) {

    }


    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {

        mLastLocation = location;
        if (mCurrLocationMarker != null) {
            mCurrLocationMarker.remove();
        }

        //Place current location marker
        LatLng latLng = new LatLng(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude());
        MarkerOptions markerOptions = new MarkerOptions();
        markerOptions.position(latLng);
//        markerOptions.title("Your Current Location");
//        markerOptions.icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_MAGENTA));
//        markerOptions.icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.home));
//        markerOptions.draggable(true);
        mCurrLocationMarker = mMap.addMarker(markerOptions);

        //move map camera
        mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(latLng));
        mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(15));

        //Set a marker drag listener
        mMap.setOnMarkerDragListener(new GoogleMap.OnMarkerDragListener() {
            @Override
            public void onMarkerDragStart(Marker marker) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onMarkerDrag(Marker marker) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onMarkerDragEnd(Marker marker) {
                mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(marker.getPosition()));
                //Get the latitude and longitude of the place where user dropped the marker
                Toast.makeText(MapsActivity.this, "Latitude:" + String.valueOf(marker.getPosition().latitude), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                homeLatitude = marker.getPosition().latitude;
                Toast.makeText(MapsActivity.this, "Longitude:" + String.valueOf(marker.getPosition().longitude), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                homeLongitude = marker.getPosition().longitude;

            }
        });


        //stop location updates
        if (mGoogleApiClient != null) {
            LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.removeLocationUpdates(mGoogleApiClient, this);
        }

    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult connectionResult) {
    }


    public void showAlertBox(String LocationName) {

        AlertDialog.Builder b1 = new AlertDialog.Builder(MapsActivity.this);
        b1.setMessage("Please select your " + LocationName + " location.\nTap anywhere on the screen to select your "
                + LocationName +
                "location and press button to confirm.");
        b1.setCancelable(false);

        b1.setPositiveButton("Ok",
                new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {

                    }
                });

        AlertDialog customAlertBox = b1.create();
        customAlertBox.show();

    }


    public void showAlertBoxForHomeLocationConfirmation(String reverseGeoStr) {

        AlertDialog.Builder b1 = new AlertDialog.Builder(MapsActivity.this);
        b1.setMessage("Confirm your home location or search again\n" + reverseGeoStr);
        b1.setCancelable(false);

        b1.setPositiveButton("Confirm",
                new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                        count = 3;

                        homeLocationFromPin.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        showAlertBox("Office");
                    }
                });

        b1.setNegativeButton("Do it again",
                new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                        Toast.makeText(MapsActivity.this, "Place Pin Again", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                });
        AlertDialog customAlertBox = b1.create();
        customAlertBox.show();

    }


    public void showAlertBoxForOfficeLocationConfirmation(String reverseGeoStr) {

        AlertDialog.Builder b1 = new AlertDialog.Builder(MapsActivity.this);
        b1.setMessage("Confirm your Office location or search again\n" + reverseGeoStr);
        b1.setCancelable(false);

        b1.setPositiveButton("Confirm",
                new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                        Intent st = new Intent(MapsActivity.this, getUserName.class);
                        startActivity(st);
                        finish();
                    }
                });

        b1.setNegativeButton("Do it again",
                new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                        Toast.makeText(MapsActivity.this, "Place Pin Again", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                });
        AlertDialog customAlertBox = b1.create();
        customAlertBox.show();

    }


    private String getAddress(double latitude, double longitude) {
        if (latitude == 0.0 || longitude == 0.0) {
            //Give default values so it does not returns null
            latitude = 42.3601;
            longitude = -71.0589;
        }
        StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
        try {
            Geocoder geocoder = new Geocoder(this, Locale.getDefault());
            List<Address> addresses = geocoder.getFromLocation(latitude, longitude, 1);
            if (addresses.size() > 0) {
                Address address = addresses.get(0);
                result.append(address.getAddressLine(0)).append("\n");
                result.append(address.getLocality()).append("\n");
                result.append(address.getAdminArea()).append("\n");
                result.append(address.getPostalCode()).append("\n");
                result.append(address.getCountryName());
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e("tag", e.getMessage());
        }

        return result.toString();
    }

    private String getNameOnly(double latitude, double longitude) {
        if (latitude == 0.0 || longitude == 0.0) {
            //Give default values so it does not returns null
            latitude = 42.3601;
            longitude = -71.0589;
        }
        StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
        try {
            Geocoder geocoder = new Geocoder(this, Locale.getDefault());
            List<Address> addresses = geocoder.getFromLocation(latitude, longitude, 1);
            if (addresses.size() > 0) {
                Address address = addresses.get(0);
                result.append(address.getAddressLine(0)).append("\n");
                result.append(address.getLocality()).append("\n");
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e("tag", e.getMessage());
        }
        return result.toString();
    }


    protected void requestPermission(String permissionType, int requestCode) {
        int permission = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,
                permissionType);

        if (permission != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,
                    new String[]{permissionType}, requestCode
            );
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode,
                                           String permissions[], int[] grantResults) {
        switch (requestCode) {
            case LOCATION_REQUEST_CODE: {

                if (grantResults.length == 0
                        || grantResults[0] != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                    Toast.makeText(this, "Unable to show location - permission required", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
                return;
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 3):

As you are requesting for location update in `onMapReady()`, You should call `mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);` in `onRequestPermissionsResult` method:

```
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String permissions[], int[] grantResults) {
        switch (requestCode) {
            case LOCATION_REQUEST_CODE: {
                // If request is cancelled, the result arrays are empty.
                if (grantResults.length > 0
                        && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

                    mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);


                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Please provide the permission", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
                break;
            }
        } 
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Looked logical and is working. Thanks. Such a small thing I was banging my head on, for hours. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

The soluion above makes it work on phones with API > 23 but it stops working with API< 23. So I worked around

```
   @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode,
                                           String permissions[], int[] grantResults) {
        switch (requestCode) {
            case LOCATION_REQUEST_CODE: {

                if (grantResults.length == 0 || grantResults[0] != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                    Toast.makeText(this, "Unable to show location - permission required", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    return;
                }

//                if (grantResults.length > 0 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
//                    mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
//                }
                else
                {
                    Toast.makeText(this,"Permission not granted",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
                break;
            }
        }
    }

}
```

and in onMapReady()

```
@Override
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
    mMap = googleMap;
    mMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_HYBRID);
    LatLng boston = new LatLng(42.3601, -71.0589);
    mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(boston));
    mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(15));

    showAlertBox("Home");

    if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission
            (this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED

            && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission
            (this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

        mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);

    } else {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
            requestPermission(Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION, LOCATION_REQUEST_CODE);
        }
    }


    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {

        buildGoogleApiClient();
        Toast.makeText(this, "Inside Perm", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        mMap.setOnMapClickListener(new GoogleMap.OnMapClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onMapClick(LatLng latLng) {

                if (count == 0) {
                    //Make the confirm button available on first tap
                    homeLocationFromPin.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    //add(point);
                    mMap.clear();
                    placedHomeMarker = new MarkerOptions().position(latLng);
                    placedHomeMarker.title("Home Location");
                    mMap.addMarker(placedHomeMarker);
                    homeLatitude = latLng.latitude;
                    homeLongitude = latLng.longitude;
                    Toast.makeText(MapsActivity.this, getNameOnly(homeLatitude, homeLongitude), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                } else {
                    officeLocationFromPin.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    placedOfficeMarker = new MarkerOptions().position(latLng);
                    placedOfficeMarker.title("Office Location");
                    mMap.addMarker(placedOfficeMarker);
                    officeLatitude = latLng.latitude;
                    officeLongitude = latLng.longitude;
                    Toast.makeText(MapsActivity.this, getNameOnly(homeLatitude, homeLongitude), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    Toast.makeText(MapsActivity.this, getNameOnly(officeLatitude, officeLongitude), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }
        });
    } else {

        buildGoogleApiClient();
        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            // TODO: Consider calling
            //    ActivityCompat#requestPermissions
            // here to request the missing permissions, and then overriding
            //   public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions,
            //                                          int[] grantResults)
            // to handle the case where the user grants the permission. See the documentation
            // for ActivityCompat#requestPermissions for more details.
            mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
        }

        mMap.setOnMapClickListener(new GoogleMap.OnMapClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onMapClick(LatLng latLng) {
                if (count == 0) {
                    //Make the confirm button available on first tap
                    homeLocationFromPin.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    //add(point);
                    mMap.clear();
                    placedHomeMarker = new MarkerOptions().position(latLng);
                    placedHomeMarker.title("Home Location");
                    mMap.addMarker(placedHomeMarker);
                    homeLatitude = latLng.latitude;
                    homeLongitude = latLng.longitude;
                    Toast.makeText(MapsActivity.this, getNameOnly(homeLatitude, homeLongitude), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                } else {
                    officeLocationFromPin.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    placedOfficeMarker = new MarkerOptions().position(latLng);
                    placedOfficeMarker.title("Office Location");
                    mMap.addMarker(placedOfficeMarker);
                    officeLatitude = latLng.latitude;
                    officeLongitude = latLng.longitude;
                    Toast.makeText(MapsActivity.this, getNameOnly(homeLatitude, homeLongitude), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    Toast.makeText(MapsActivity.this, getNameOnly(officeLatitude, officeLongitude), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }
        });
    }
}//End of onMap Ready
```

Comment: Yeah, the solution above is specifically for ur problem mentioning in question. The additional modification is expected to be done by the question maker as needed. That does not make an answer wrong. Though there are numerous ways to work the above code for all 'API' versions, your one is quite good, the up-vote is also mine. Cheers!

Comment: I am not calling it wrong. I greatly appreciate your help.  And I have also upvoted your answer.Thanks again.